# Concurrent asynchronous execution more task

Tags: android-asynctask

hello，i want to send messages to more IPs using TCP,i want the messages Concurrent asynchronous send to the IPs,not one by one.

```
  @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {



        for(int i=0;i<CommonUtil.ipList.size();i++){

            if(!CommonUtil.ipList.get(i).equals(fromIp)){

               TCPUDPCommunicate.sendSingleMessage(CommonUtil.ipList.get(i), CommonUtil.local_port, xmldata);


        return true;

    }else {
        Log.i("ee","CommonUtil.ipList.get(i) is null");
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET 4.0 or above, you could use `Parallel.ForEach()`. It should free you from the concerns of batching tasks on a fixed number of threads.

Look it up here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The code would look like this.

```
int notFromIpCount = 0;

Parallel.ForEach(CommonUtil.ipList, ip => 
{
    bool isNotFromIp = !ip.equals(fromIp);

    if (isNotFromIp)
    {
        TCPUDPCommunicate.sendSingleMessage(ip, CommonUtil.local_port, xmldata);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref notFromIpCount); 
    }
    else 
    {
        // Log message
    }
}

return notFromIpCount > 0;
```

The Task Parallel Library is a bit slow with a debugger attached, but profile it in Release mode without a debugger and you should barely see a performance difference compared to manually created threads.

PS. The log message is confusing. If `CommonUtil.ipList.get(i)` was `null`, your code would have raised a `NullReferenceException`.